# Error with IndexOf C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm obviously missing something here..

I'm writing a function that returns the number of substrings delimited by a particular string. 
Here is the rather simple function -

```
public static FuncError DCount(String v1, String v2, ref Int32 result) {
        result = 0;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(v1)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(v2)) {
            return null;
        }

        int ct = 1;
        int ix = 0;
        int nix = 0;

        do {
            nix = v1.IndexOf(v2, ix);
            if (nix >= 0) {
                ct++;

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(
string.Format("{0} found at {1} count={2} result = {3}",
v2, nix, ct, v1.Substring(nix,1)));
                ix = nix + v2.Length;
            }
        } while (nix >= 0);
        result = ct;
        return null;
    }
```

The problem comes when I call with a special character that is being used as a separator in a particular situation. It's returning lots of false positives. From the Debug.Print the first and the last argument should always be the same.

```
þ found at 105 count=2 result = t
þ found at 136 count=3 result = t
þ found at 152 count=4 result = þ
þ found at 249 count=5 result = t
þ found at 265 count=6 result = t
þ found at 287 count=7 result = t
þ found at 317 count=8 result = t
þ found at 333 count=9 result = þ
þ found at 443 count=10 result = þ
þ found at 553 count=11 result = þ
þ found at 663 count=12 result = þ
þ found at 773 count=13 result = þ
þ found at 883 count=14 result = þ
þ found at 993 count=15 result = þ
```

If I pass the þ as a char it works fine.
If I split the string using þ as a delimiter it returns the correct number of elements.
As for the incorrectly identified 't', there are other 't's in the results that are not being picked up, so it's not a character conversion issue.

Confused ...

Thanks

Comment: Try to give the proper name of variables. it will help you as well as us alot

Comment: Can you post the actual code used to test here, meaning the code that calls that function? Preferably by escaping out the special character so we don't have to rely on web encoding to convey the right one.

Comment: String comparisons have a knack for produces unintended results.  Always be explicit about the comparison rule you want to use.  Which likely should be StringComparison.Ordinal here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`StringComparison.Ordinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) to get culture agnostic string matching.

using Lasse V. Karlsen's [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15500523/580951):

```
string x = "uma thurman";
x.IndexOf("þ", StringComparison.Ordinal).Dump();
```

Will result in `-1`.

See [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I found that using 'þ' instead of "þ" works too. Also if searched character is a string then we can cast to to char by search[0] and it will give -1 as well. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is how different cultures represent characters, and in some cases combine them.

The letter you're searching for, [Thorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_%28letter%29), can apparently be represented by the `th` letters.

Try this code in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

```
void Main()
{
    string x = "uma thurman";
    x.IndexOf("þ").Dump();
}
```

It will output `4`.

*(Note that I run this program on a machine in Norway, it may or may not have an impact on the results)*

This is the same "problem" as the german letter for double S - ß - can be found in words with two s's together, *in some cultures*.

Comment: Side note: It's not a Sho the Original Poster and you are using, it's a Thorn letter. The former is of ancient Greek origin and not equivalent to "th", while the latter is a Nordic letter (Old Norse, Icelandic and others) equivalent to an unvoiced "th", comparable to Greek Theta (Θ).

Comment: The worst is that I had a checking for text length when I was comparing:

`string text = "ß";
text.IndexOf("s") => 0
text.Length => 1`

So length of s and ß will be also the same... the only solution so far `text.IndexOf('s') => -1`

Answer (score 0):

You're using [an overload of `IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx) which:

> performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) search using the current culture

Therefore results depend on the `CurrentCulture` of your thread. Most cultures regard the [letter thorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_%28letter%29) as equivalent to `th`. See Lasse's answer.

For example, the old norse god called Þórr is often written Thor in English, the initial letter being pronounced as the "Th" in "Thursday" (Thor's day).

To solve your problem, change `v1.IndexOf(v2, ix)` into:

```
v1.IndexOf(v2, ix, StringComparison.Ordinal)
```

see [the doc on that overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224424.aspx).

An ordinal comparison compares the `char` values one by one in a naive way, simply comparing their numerical values. In contrast, a culture-dependent comparison does a lot of normalization, both with respect to different representations of accented lettes, and with respect to different lettes that the culture considers equivalent. This is very important in collation also, for example with an ordinal comparison the string `"naïve"` comes ***after*** the string `"nasty"` in a sorting (since the `System.Char` value `'ï'` has a higher numerical value than `'s'`).